# How to attach event handler to Google charts?

Tags: jquery, google-visualization, jquery-events

I'm familiar with how to attach a select handler via the API:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'select', selectHandler);
```

However, this only work if a user selects an element on the chart, for example click on a bar. The listener doesn't fire if a user clicks on any whitespace in the chart. I want to add a feature where if the user clicks white space on the chart, it opens a new page. Can this be done? I've tried adding a jQuery event handler on the containing div, but the event never fires. I assume the chart prevents event propagation.